# Natural Language processing for getting qualitative info

Tags: nlp

I have a requirement for which I do not know if NL can do it. Plz advise.

My requirement is to scan a sentence in english language and figure out some qualitative info about it. Such as , what are the subjects , nouns in the sentence and what is said about them is a descriptive , suggestive  or does it affects positively or negatively.

As an example, lets say I have a Fan page in facebook , and someone posts a post on my wall. I need to know if the post says something good or bad about me and accordingly I can map it to a perception scale from , say -10 to +10.

Can something like this be done with with Natural language processing toolkits?
If no, then what is the way.

Thanks in advance
Shyam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Natural Language Processing methods *can* do what you ask for:

To find out which are the "nouns" in a text is called [POS-Tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pos-tagging).
Identifying the syntactical strucure of sentences is called [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Human_languages). Depending on your parsing method and how strict the syntax of the language is you might want to look into [semantic role labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling) aswell to find subjects/objects in a sentence. Classifying the polarity (positive/negative) of a statement is called [sentiment analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis).

The Python [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) provides some tools you can get started with, but sentiment analysis is an active research area and a task where a lot of other NLP-methods have to work together, so it is certainly not the easiest field to get started with in NLP. Anyways, a survey of the academic research in the field can be found in [Pang & Lee (2008)](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/omsa/omsa.pdf).